# How to prove that $(G,*)$ is a group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\mathbb{R_0}\times\mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{R_0}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{{0}\}$.  Define operation $*$ on $G$ by $(a,b)*(x,y)=(ax,a^2y+b)$.

I'd like to prove that $(G,*)$ is a group.  Immediately $(a,b), (x,y)\in G$ implies $(ax,a^2y+b)\in G$.

I need help to prove associativity of $*$.

Thanks for replies.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb R/0$ or $\mathbb R\setminus 0$?

Comment: You have a typo "$(ax, a^2+b)$" should be $(ax, a^2y + b)$

Comment: You need to *prove* your claim that $G$ is closed under $\ast$, not just state it.

Comment: For what it is worth, this is an example of a semidirect product of groups. In this case, for each element of $r=\mathbb R_0$, we hav an automorphism $\phi_r$ of $(\mathbb R,+)$ defined as $\phi_r(x)=r^2x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Proof of associativity:

Assume $(a,b), \ (u,v) , \ (x,y)\in G$. Then

$$
\big((a,b) * (x,y)  \big) * (u,v) = (ax,a^2y+b ) * (u,v) = (axu, a^2 x^2v + a^2y+b)
$$

On the other hand, 
$$
(a,b) * \big((x,y) * (u,v) \big)  = (a,b) *  (xu,x^2v + y ) =\big (axu, a^2(x^2 v +y) + b\big) = (axu, a^2x^2 v +a^2y + b ).
$$

Clearly two expressions coincide, therefore $G$ is associative under the $*$ operation

Answer (score 3):

1. First note that $*$ is well-defined. If $(a,b), (x,y) \in G$, then $a,x \in \Bbb R^*$, so $ax \in \Bbb R^*$, which means that $(ax, a^2 y + b) \in \Bbb R^* \times \Bbb R = G$.
2. We show that $(1, 0) \in G$ is the neutral element of $G$: 
   $$\begin{align*} (1,0) * (x,y) &= (1\cdot x, 1^2 y + 0) = (x,y) \\ (x,y) * (1,0) &= (x\cdot 1, x^2 \cdot 0 + y) = (x,y) \end{align*}$$
3. Next we show, that for $(x,y) \in G$, $\left(\frac 1 x, -\frac{y}{x^2} \right) \in G$ is the inverse of $(x,y)$:
   $$\begin{align*}(x,y) * \left( \frac{1}{x}, - \frac{y}{x^2} \right) &= \left( x \cdot \frac 1 x, x^2 \cdot \left(-\frac{y}{x^2} \right) + y \right) = (1,0) \\ \left( \frac 1 x, - \frac{y}{x^2} \right) * (x,y) &= \left( \frac{1}{x} \cdot x, \left( \frac{1}{x}\right)^2 \cdot y - \frac{y}{x^2} \right) = (1,0) \end{align*}$$
4. It remains to show, that the operation $*$ is associative. Let $(a,b), (c,d), (e,f) \in G$. Then 
   $$\begin{align*} \left( (a,b) * (c,d) \right) * (e,f) &= \left( ac, a^2d+b) *(e,f) \right) = \left( ace, a^2c^2f + a^2d + b\right) \; , \\ (a,b) * \left( (c,d) * (e,f) \right) &= (a,b) * \left( ce, c^2f + d\right) = \left(ace, a^2 c^2 f+a^2 d + b\right) \; . \end{align*}$$

So we have shown, that $G$ is a group.

Answer (score 0):

Associativity shouldn't pose much of a problem.

$((a,b) * (c,d)) * (e,f)$

$= (ac,a^2d + b) * (e,f)$

$= (ace,a^2c^2f + a^2d + b)$

Now perform a similar manipulation with $(a,b) * ((c,d) * (e,f))$ and you should get the same expression.